# Is there a way to make :dbg available in exrm releases?

Tags: elixir, exrm

When I run my application in my dev environment with

```
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

I am able to use :dbg.tracer to look into my code. But when I build an exrm release and run it with

```
bin/myapp console
```

When I try to use :dbg.tracer it tells me "module :dbg is not available". Is there a way to make :dbg available in an exrm release? That would be really handy.

Comment: I think you need to add `:runtime_tools` to your `applications` in `mix.exs` and then create the release: http://erlang.org/doc/man/runtime_tools_app.html

Comment: ^ Same thing if you want observer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server does not have `erlang-runtime-tools` installed, but your dev environment does. To address this in Debian, you can run `sudo apt-get install erlang-runtime-tools`. Once that is done, you should be able to run `:dbg.tracer/0` from your console without any extra steps.

In the future, if you want to install Erlang along with all of its applications such as :crypto, :dbg, etc... then I suggest you install `esl-erlang`. In Ubuntu, for example, `sudo apt-get install esl-erlang`.